# Демон и приложение Flask, подключение к одной БД Firebird 3, блокировки

Tags: python, flask, firebird, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Всем привет!
Есть приложение на Flask.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile(filename='settings.py', silent=True)
db = SQLAlchemy()  
db.init_app(app)
```

Как правильно нужно подключится к БД или какие настройки сделать, чтобы демон мог параллельно обрабатывать и делать записи в базу, а приложение Flask показывало вебку.
Сейчас при попытке открыть веб я получаю 502 ошибку, а в логах:

```
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE:
-902\n- I/O error during "lock" operation for file "main.fdb"\n- Database 
already opened with engine instance, incompatible with current', -902, 
335544344)
```

Перепробовал уже очень много различных вариаций, но результата нет.
Подключение к БД происходит напрямую к файлу, не через сеть.
Когда я останавливаю демона, то веб работает нормально, то есть селекты из БД нормально отрабатывают.
Если же демона запустить, то вебка снова не работает.
Буду рад рабочему примеру, как можно такое реализовать.
Спасибо!

update:
Пробовал ещё уровень изоляции БД настроить вот таким образом:

```
from fdb.fbcore import ISOLATION_LEVEL_READ_COMMITED_LEGACY
class TPBAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    def apply_driver_hacks(self, app_, info, options):
        if 'isolation_level' not in options:
            options['isolation_level'] = ISOLATION_LEVEL_READ_COMMITED_LEGACY
        return super(TPBAlchemy, self).apply_driver_hacks(app_, info, options)
```

И вместо:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Писал:

```
db = TPBAlchemy()
```

Но это лишь породило другую ошибку:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'isolation_level' sent to create_engine(),
using configuration FBDialect_fdb/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the
keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebird под никсами хранит лок-файлы в папке /tmp/firebird или где укажешь переменной среды FIREBIRD_LOCK. У пользователя, под которым запускается исполняемый модуль, должен быть доступ уровня создания/изменения файлов в этой папке.

Comment: Запускается всё под рутом. Знаю, что не секурно, но это не продакшн, так что пока без разницы.

Comment: >Database already opened with engine instance, incompatible with current. Попробуйте стереть все lock-файлы.

Comment: Ну после этого работает, пока не создастся новый lock-файл.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить пользователя, под которым это все запускается, в группу firebird.

Comment: Можно будет попробовать. Ну думаю, что проблема всё же не в этом. Переписал всё на чистый SQL и использую fdb. Перед каждым запросом открываю новый коннект, а после закрываю его. Таким образом локов нет. Не помог даже ISOLATION_LEVEL, поэтому одним коннектом не получается пользоваться.

Answer (score 0):

Какая строка подключения в веб-приложении и в демоне? Наверно, просто полное имя базы данных (ну или алиас из файла aliases.conf), а не что-то вроде host:databasename или \host\databasename? Если да, то укажите и там, и там строку подключения xnet://databasename

Проект, наверно, раньше работал с Firebird 2.5 или более ранней версией. Там подключение просто по имени файла означало подключение к серверу Firebird по локальному протоколу XNET. Но в 3.0 подключение просто по имени файла означает Embedded-режим, то есть каждое приложение само себе сервер БД. Кто первый успел подключится, тот и получил базу монопольно. А для работы через XNET теперь нужно явно указывать протокол в строке подключения.

P.S. У Вас же наверно linux? тогда XNET не пойдёт, нужен TCP/IP. Строка подключения должна быть inet://databasename